# Selecting soundcard in Java for playing sound

Tags: java, audio

I have multiple sound cards in/connected to my computer.

Now, I want to play sound via a sound card that is not the default sound card device. Is this possible with Java Sound API? How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this link :http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84314/wired-for-sound/

Comment: Thanks, but this only shows how to play sound on the default line, but not how to play sound on another sound device

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*

AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);

Mixer.Info[] arrMixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

// Get a sound clip resource.
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(arrMixerInfo[1]);

// Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
clip.open(audioIn);
clip.start();
clip.drain();
clip.close();
```

`arrMixerInfo[0]` means the default sound card. This code can only play a .wav file

Comment: This is not entirely true. I have only the default sound card and a virtual cable. Now if I print out the first three devices from `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()`, I get this output:
(1): Primary Sound Driver
(2): Speakers (Conexant 20672 SmartAudio HD) and (3)
CABLE-A Input (VB-Audio Cable A)
While the second sound driver being the default one (thus the same one as the first)